# Create an ActiveX checkbox that check and unchecks all other checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex

I've got a sheet with a lot of checkboxes. The first one has the caption Check All and when you click it, all checkboxes should be checked. That works fine, but I also want to uncheck all the checkboxes by unchecking it and I can't get that to work. I get the error 1004. This is the code I'm trying:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
On Error GoTo finished
For i = 2 To 200
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then ' <- this line gives the 1004 error
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True
    End If
Next i
Exit Sub
finished:
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the *Text* of the error message?  Are you sure you have a checkbox with that name?  FYI if this code is in the sheet code module then you should use `Me` to refer to the sheet, instead of `ActiveSheet`.  That way when you eventually have code which changes the checkbox values when the sheet is *not* active, it won't break.

Comment: The text is "Application-defined or object-defined error" https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/application-defined-or-object-defined-error I do have a checkbox with that name. It's created with the press of a button and is then renamed to Checkbox1 in the code. If I right click on it and select View Code the sub `CheckBox1_Click()` is shown.

Comment: That's kind of a significant detail - creating controls at run-time with associated code in the sheet module will give you all sorts of problems - in order for everything to link up the sheet module needs to be recompiled, and that presents a challenge....   You might need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me - I'd suggest a couple minor changes - use `Me` in place of `activesheet`, and simplify the logic for setting the other checkboxes.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, bOn As Boolean

    bOn = Me.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value
    For i = 2 To 200
        Me.OLEObjects("Checkbox" & i).Object.Value = bOn
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, got the same 1004 error at the line `bOn = Me.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value` Strange!